# Inequality concerning the Gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, special-functions, inequality

For each $n>0$, how do we prove that $$\Gamma'(n+1)> \log{n} \cdot \Gamma(n+1)$$

- I had spent about half an hour on this question, but just could find any way of proceeding for the solution.
- Wikipedia page gave me an interesting identity $$\Gamma'(n+1)= n! \cdot \Biggl( - \gamma + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}\Biggr)$$ But i don't know how it can be applied here.

Comment: A link to the wikipedia page would be handy.

Comment: If the identity holds we would only need to prove that $\log n <\sum \frac{1}{k} -\gamma$, i.e. $$\sum \frac{1}{k}-\log n +\phi(n)>\gamma$$ for some positive function $\phi$. Finding such a $\phi$ might be done using some refinement in the estimate of the integral test, I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if we rearrange the inequality to

$$\frac{\Gamma^{\prime}(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)} > \log n$$

and then note that

$$\frac{\Gamma^{\prime}(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)}=-\gamma+\sum_{j=1}^n \frac1{j}$$

you should be able to easily deduce the inequality.

Comment: Note also that $\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac1{j}-\log n$.

Comment: M: Oh ho! I missed the killer blow!